# Can "open-shellness" be accounted for in terms of an observable? Or is it "just" an artefact of one-electron approximations?

Tags: many-body

In DFT or Hartree-Fock calculations, it is common to refer to a ground state as open-shell if, when performing an spin-unrestricted self-consistent computation, the orbitals are spin-dependent. If the orbitals obtained are the same than in a spin-restricted calculation, the ground state is said to be closed shell.

Now my question is, is this an artificial by-product of the self-consistent one-electron calculation? Or is it a more "fundamental" property that can be encoded in the expected value of some observable $\hat{\mathcal{O}}$?  It is not weird to encounter quantities that are very useful from a conceptual point of view and do not correspond to any observable (e.g, partial charges, orbitals' eigenenergies,...)

For example, given a general many-body wavefunction of a multi-electronic system, $\Psi(x_1,...,x_N),$ is there any observable $\hat{\mathcal{O}}$ such that the value $\langle \Psi  \vert  \hat{\mathcal{O}} \vert \Psi\rangle$ can be linked to either "open-shellness" or "closed-shellness"?